# Simpler way to update big decimal column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a simple budgeting app, and have a line of code that feels convoluted and overly complex. For context:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :month_budget
  has_many :expenditures, as: :spendable
end

class MonthBudget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :expenditures, as: spendable
end

class Expenditure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spendable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Within my Expenditure class, I have defined a class method, add_expenditure:

```
class Expenditure < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.add_expenditure(user, params) #params passed will be in [:expenditure][*keys], in which possible keys are [:amount] or [:location]
    if user.month_budget
      user.month_budget.expenditures.create(params)
      new_amount = user.month_budget.current_amount += params[:amount].to_d
      user.month_budget.update(current_amount: new_amount)
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to add a value to the initial month_budget.current_amount column, and then record this new number to the database?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `increment!` method (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21).

However, I am not sure if it works well with big decimals.

```
class Expenditure < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.add_expenditure(user, params)
    if user.month_budget
      user.month_budget.expenditures.create(params)
      user.month_budget.increment!(:current_amount, params[:amount].to_d)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `increment!` isn't defined for BigDecimal. Thanks though!